# Application for taking pretty screenshots (like OS X does)

Tags: software-recommendation, screenshot

I've been building a website for a guy who uses Mac OS X and occasionally he sends me screenshots of bugs. They come out looking like this:

[image: A pretty screenshot]

This is fairly typical of Mac screenshots. You get the window decorations, the shadow from the window and a white or transparent background (not the desktop wallpaper -- I've checked).

Compare this to an Ubuntu window-shot (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print screen</kbd>):

[image]

It's impossible to keep a straight face and say the Ubuntu one anywhere near as elegant.

My question is: **Is there an application that can do this in Ubuntu?**

**Edit:** Follow up: Is there an application that can do this in one move? Shutter is pretty good but running the plugin for every screenshot is pretty tiresome as it doesn't seem to remember my preference (I want south-shadow and that requires selecting south, then clicking refresh, then save) and it's more clicks than I'd like.

Is there a simple way of telling shutter I want south-shadow for all screenshots (except entire desktop and area-selection)?

Comment: but if you take a screenshot of just the window you wont get the wallpaper?!

Comment: Kubuntu's default application is very good, Mac's or Window's I think are worse. It's called KSnapshot, I don't know how it works on Ubuntu but on Kubuntu it is great. Keep in mind, everything Ubuntu has, there is a better alternative in KDE :)

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Related (I haven't tried it, at least not yet): https://github.com/Cabbagec/gnome-screenshot-heavy-shadow

Answer (score 49, accepted):

## Using [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) [image]

- First go to Edit -> Preferences and tick the two options mentioned below .

[image]

- Now Take the screenshot of a window and right-click and select run a plugin .

[image]

- Now select Hard Shadow and run it .

[image]

- Your Final Screenshot will look like this .

[image: Pretty Screenshot!]

## Using gnome-screenshot

- Launch 'Take Screenshot' from the dash and select 'Include the window border' with the Effect Drop 'Shadow' or 'Border' and then take the screenshot.

[image]

- To do the same using the terminal ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> ) paste

  gnome-screenshot -w -b -d 5 -e border

where 5 is delay in seconds and border can be replaced with shadow for 'Drop Shadow' .

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not hit <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and an alias? Wouldn't that make things easier? EXAMPLE: <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> (Run Command window shows) gscreenshot (Gnome-screenshot runs)

Comment: `gnome-screenshot -wbe shadow` is very effective.

Answer (score 14):

## [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) [image: install shutter]

You can achieve this in Shutter. To grab a whole window, including decorations, you can right click on the notification icon then click 'Window under Cursor' or from the application window, click the window icon (4th from the left in the toolbar). You can then select a window with your mouse to take the screenshot of that window.

To make rounded window decorations look better, go into Edit->Preferences, click the 'Advanced' tab and tick 'Force rounded window corners'.

[image: Force Rounded Window Corners]

To add a shadow effect, once you have taken a screenshot, click Screenshot->Run a Plugin... and choose 'Hard Shadow' then click 'Run'.

[image: Choose a plug-in]

You can then edit the options for the shadow and click 'Save' to apply the effect.

[image: Hard Shadow]

The end result looks something like this:

[image: End Result]

Comment: But does it have a plugin to draw hand-drawn circles?

Comment: @Random832 that's not a plugin but you can do it by clicking the edit button on the toolbar (second button from the right).

Answer (score 7):

### Customizable automatic solution using `scrot` and `imagemagick`

---

**Overview**

`scrot` is a highly customizable CLI screenshot utility. In this example we utilize its capability to pass screenshots to external programs in order to add a pretty dropshadow effect with `imagemagick`.

**Note**: This method does not work properly under Unity and more than likely won't work on any other WM with rounded borders, either. You can still capture images of course, but the drop shadow will be applied not only to the window but also to parts of the background. You might be able to troubleshoot this by replacing `scrot` with `gnome-screenshot` and adjust the script accordingly.

---

**Sample shot**

[image]

---

**Dropshadow script**

```
#!/bin/bash
# NAME:         dropshadow.sh
# VERSION:      
# AUTHOR:       (c) 2013 Glutanimate
# DESCRIPTION:  - adds transparent dropshadow to images (e.g. screenshots)
#               - moves them to predefined screenshot folder
# FEATURES:     
# DEPENDENCIES: imagemagick suite
#
# LICENSE:      MIT license (http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)
#
# NOTICE:       THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED,
#               INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
#               PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE
#               LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, 
#               TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE 
#               OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
#
#
# USAGE:        dropshadow.sh <image>

SCREENSHOTFOLDER="$HOME/Pictures/Screenshots"


FILE="${1}"
FILENAME="${FILE##*/}"
FILEBASE="${FILENAME%.*}"

convert "${FILE}" \( +clone -background black -shadow 80x20+0+15 \) +swap -background transparent -layers merge +repage "$SCREENSHOTFOLDER/${FILEBASE}.png"

rm "$FILE" #remove this line to preserve original image
```

**Note**: Original convert command-line by [Stephen Connolly](http://javaadventure.blogspot.de/2011/10/how-to-add-mac-like-shadow-to-your.html).

---

**How to integrate it into your system**

Proceed to bind the following command-line to a key of your choice and you should be ready to go:

```
scrot -szb -e 'dropshadow.sh $f'
```

If you are running LXDE/Openbox like me you can add the following keybind to your `lxde-rc.xml`:

```
<keybind key="C-Print"><action name="Execute"><execute>scrot -szb -e 'dropshadow.sh $f'</execute></action></keybind>
```

**Note**: Make sure to either include `dropshadow.sh` in your `PATH` or to replace it with the actual location of the script in your file system.

---

**Usage**

Hit the keyboard combo you defined in the previous step (e.g. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd>) and click on a window of your choice.

Comment: I imagine this fares less well with rounded corners but it's a nice solution nonetheless.

Comment: @Oli: thanks! I just tried it out under Unity and you're right. If you set `scrot` to include the window borders it will capture a small area around the actual window, including whatever is behind. It's a bummer, but what can you do :/. I'll add a note to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

KWIN (KDE's window manager) added a functionality like that recently: https://svn.reviewboard.kde.org/r/4814/
KWIN is offering the API via DBUS. If you are using KDE you can simply use KSnapshot to get a screenshot like that ("window under cursor").

If we want to have this functionality in Unity(or Classic Desktop) Compiz needs to offer an API for it. I have written a feature request for it:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/781280

I would love to implement it for Shutter, as well ;-)

Comment: As always, KDE alternatives are way better.

Answer (score 4):

**KSnapshot**

[image]

A really great application from KDE, to make a screenshot just press PrtScreen, you don't need plugins or any other complicated stuff.
I am not sure if it works on Ubuntu but on Kubuntu it works just great.
Here is a link to the "official" page: http://kde.org/applications/graphics/ksnapshot/

To install it on Ubuntu try writing into the terminal: `sudo apt-get install ksnapshot`

Answer (score 3):

To answer your follow-up question ("Is there a simple way of telling shutter I want south-shadow for all screenshots?"), unfortunately no. There is an open [request to allow automatically running plugins](https://bugs.launchpad.net/shutter/+bug/365368).

Answer (score 2):

File: screenshot_window.sh (/home/)

```
#!/bin/bash

#Take Screenshot Of Current Window
#facebook.com/NguyenChanhDai.1408

FOLDER="$HOME/Pictures/Screenshots"

FILENAME=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`

gnome-screenshot -w -f $FILENAME #take screenshot of current window using GnomeScreenshot

convert "$FILENAME" \( +clone -background black -shadow 80x20+0+15 \) +swap -background white -layers merge +repage "$FOLDER/$FILENAME.png" #dropshadow using ImageMagick

xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -i $FOLDER/$FILENAME.png #paste image to clipboard

rm "$FILENAME" #remove file

echo "Success! Copied to Clipboard"
```

Create folder: Screenshots (/home/Pictures/)

---

[Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQXJI.png)

Press **Ctrl + D** : Capture screenshot of current window , 
Press **Ctrl + V** : Paste image from clipboard

Answer (score 0):

If you use Google Chrome or Chromium then there is an extension than will capture all of the screen, a visible part of the page or capture a selected area.

[Google Chrome: Awesome Screenshot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce#)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Compiz?
If so, go to Compiz Settings (you must install compiz-settings if you have not done so yet) and:

Activate the screenshot plugin.

Set the folder to which it saves.

Then all you have to do is press [Super] and [Click and Drag]. The area you select will be saved to the destination you have set.

Comment: While this is a nice trick - I don't see how this answers the question about taking pretty screenshots one window (per the description and examples)

Comment: I was so used to using ctrl+cmd+shift+4 on the iMac that I barely if ever used the window option, I misunderstood. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a mac, like screenshots is possible to be made by simply changing the default gnome-screenshot behaviour. You don't need shutter for that :)

On 
http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/how-to-take-area-screenshots-in-gnome-take-quick-area-selection-screenshots-in-g-linux-and-bsd/

You can read thorough tutorial for improving GNOME default screenshot behaviour and how to assign keys for region selection screenshota with added the drop shadow / border effects in.

Best